# Seleccionar la fecha estando en un fragmento desde un fragmento

Tags: java, android, android-studio

El problema que tengo es que estando ya en un fragmento del menú lateral quiero pulsar un botón a partir del cual me lleve a otro fragmento para seleccionar la fecha. La cuestión es que al llamar a un fragmento desde dentro de otro fragmento el programa falla.
Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo llamar a un fragmento con la fecha estando ya dentro de otro fragmento?
Adjunto mi código:
FragmentoFecha

```
package com.example.proyecto;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class FragmentoFecha extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    OnFechaSeleccionada f;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        f = (OnFechaSeleccionada) getActivity();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        int agno = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, agno, mes, dia);

        return dpd;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int agno, int mes, int dia) {
        f.onResultadoFecha(agno, mes, dia);
    }

    public interface OnFechaSeleccionada {
        public void onResultadoFecha(int agno, int mes, int dia);
    }
}
```

FragmentoEjercicios

```
public class FragmentoEjercicios extends Fragment
        implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, FragmentoFecha.OnFechaSeleccionada {

    ConexionSQLiteHelper conn;

    SearchView svBuscador;
    Button btnAsignar, btnAgnadir;
    EditText etPeso;

    ArrayList<Ejercicio> listaEjercicios = new ArrayList<>();

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm;
    RecyclerView rv;

    AdaptadorEjercicios ae;

    int pos = 0;
    int idEj = 0;
    String idUs = "";


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmento_ejercicios, container, false);

        conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(getContext(), "bdgimnasio", null, 1);

        svBuscador = view.findViewById(R.id.sv_buscador);
        btnAsignar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_asignarFecha);
        btnAgnadir = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_agnadirEjercicio);
        etPeso = view.findViewById(R.id.et_peso);

        consultarListaEjercicios();

        ae = new AdaptadorEjercicios(listaEjercicios, getContext());

        lm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        rv = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_ejercicios);
        rv.setLayoutManager(lm);
        rv.setAdapter(ae);

        //Función para inicializar el SearchView
        initListener();

        leerFichero();


        btnAsignar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /*FragmentoFecha ff = new FragmentoFecha();
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction(R.id.fragmentoEjercicios, ff)
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();*/
            }
        });
        
        ae.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pos = rv.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Selección " +
                        listaEjercicios.get(pos).getNombreEj(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                idEj = listaEjercicios.get(pos).getIdEj();
            }
        });

        btnAgnadir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addUsuarioEjercicio();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void consultarListaEjercicios() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getReadableDatabase();
        Ejercicio e = null;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Utilidades.TABLA_EJERCICIOS, null);

        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            e = new Ejercicio();
            e.setIdEj(cursor.getInt(0));
            e.setNombreEj(cursor.getString(1));
            e.setZonaTrabajada(cursor.getString(2));
            e.setIntensidad(cursor.getString(3));

            listaEjercicios.add(e);
        }

        cursor.close();
    }

    //Función para aplicar la implementación del SearchView
    private void initListener() {
        svBuscador.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }

    public void addUsuarioEjercicio() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_ID, idUs);
        values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_ID_EJ, idEj);
        values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_FECHA_REALIZADO, "2021-03-29");
        values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_PESO, etPeso.getText().toString());

        db.insert(Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIOS_EJERCICIOS, null, values);

        db.close();

    }

    public void leerFichero() {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        try {
            fileInputStream = getActivity().openFileInput("idUsuario.txt");
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            idUs = bufferedReader.readLine();
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        ae.filtro(newText);
        ae.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResultadoFecha(int agno, int mes, int dia) {
        Log.i("prueba", "hola");
    }
}
```

El problema me sucede en la siguiente parte del código y básicamente es que no sé como llamar a ese fragmento.

```
btnAsignar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /*FragmentoFecha ff = new FragmentoFecha();
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction(R.id.fragmentoEjercicios, ff)
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();*/
            }


        });
```

Gracias de antemano por las respuestas.

Este es el layout del FragmentoEjercicios(está en el menú lateral)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/contenedor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentoEjercicios">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_asignarFecha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="276dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:text="Asignar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_asignarFecha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:text="Asignar fecha:"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_peso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
        android:text="Peso:"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_mostrarFecha"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="152dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_ejercicios"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="383dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_agnadirEjercicio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="644dp"
        android:text="Añadir Ejercicio"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/sv_buscador"
        android:layout_width="336dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_peso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="108dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: ¿Qué error imprime el `LogCat` luego de realizada la acción que genera el error?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.proyecto.MenuSlideActivity cannot be cast to com.example.proyecto.FragmentoFecha$OnFechaSeleccionada

Comment: ¿Y cómo se llama el FramLayout donde cargas tu Fragment? ¿Puedes mostrarnos el layout de la actividad en la que cargas el fragmento?

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta con el layout.

Comment: Claro pero lo que te pedí es el layout de la actividad en donde estás cargando los Fragmentos, lo que tú me muestras es el layout del FragmentEjercicios...

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es hacer un replace de un fragment por otro. Se debe modificar el R.id.fragment por el identificador que tengas establecido.

```
Fragment fragmentoFecha  = new FragmentoFecha();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.fragment, fragmentoFecha)
           .commit();
```

Comment: He probado tu código y me sigue saliendo el mismo error, java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.proyecto.MenuSlideActivity cannot be cast to com.example.proyecto.FragmentoFecha$OnFechaSeleccionada

Comment: ¿Tienes el código subido a github o en algún repo publico para poder probarlo?

Comment: El problema creo que es que quiero pasar de un fragmento que esta dentro de un menú lateral a otro fragmento que no está en ese menú lateral.

Comment: El Código no lo he subido porque lo estoy cambiando continuamente.